# ¿Cómo hago para inserta un registro que contiene una clave foranea?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy usando MariaDB (phpMyAdmin)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Crea la tabla usuario y establece como propiedad que el nombre de usuario es unico y no se
puede repetir

```
CREATE TABLE usuario 
(
    fk_NombreUsuario VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Contrasena VARCHAR   (10) NOT NULL,
    TipoUsuario VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk4 FOREIGN KEY (fk_NombreUsuario) REFERENCES profesor (NombreUsuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk5 FOREIGN KEY (fk_NombreUsuario) REFERENCES alumno (NombreUsuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE KEY (`fk_NombreUsuario`)
);

CREATE TABLE profesor 
(
    ClaveNomina INT (8) KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    ApellidoPaterno VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    ApellidoMaterno VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    NombreUsuario VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    INDEX ( `NombreUsuario`)
);

CREATE TABLE alumno 
(
    Matricula INT (8)  KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    ApellidoPaterno VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    ApellidoMaterno VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    NombreUsuario VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    INDEX ( `NombreUsuario`)
);
```

**Esto es lo que pretendo hacer:**

Al intentar registrar un usuario nuevo, este guarda sus datos personales en la **tabla** **profesor** o **alumno** y de manera automatica **en otra tabla usuario** guarda, contrasena y el tipo de usuario.

Estas son las consultas que estoy usando para guardar los registros

**Insertar datos personales:**

```
 INSERT INTO profesor (ClaveNomina, Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, NombreUsuario)  
 VALUES ( '34567890', 'Guillermo', 'Pasa', 'Dulce', 'Guillen' );
```

**Insertar datos para crear el usuario**

```
 INSERT INTO `usuario`(`fk_NombreUsuario`, `Contrasena`, `TipoUsuario`) VALUES ('Guillen','23454656', 'Maestro');
```

El problema es que aparece un error al hacer la segunda consulta

consulta SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `usuario`(`fk_NombreUsuario`, `Contrasena`, `TipoUsuario`) VALUES ('Guillen','23454656', 'Maestro')
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`phpws`.`usuario`, CONSTRAINT `fk5` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_NombreUsuario`) REFERENCES `alumno` (`NombreUsuario`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: estas definiendo fk_NombreUsuario VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,.. eso no la hace not null por defecto? y no la estas pasando en el insert

Comment: ¿Qué me sugieres en este caso?

Comment: No tenes que agregat el nombre del uauario al insert?

Comment: Ya he hecho la modificación, ahora aparece un mensaje más, espera en lo que modifico la publicación

Comment: El error se debe a que estás intentando ingresar un valor en `usuario` que viola la integridad referencial, ya que no existe en la tabla `alumno`. Si en alumno no hay nadie que se llame `Guillén` vas a tener ese error. De todos modos tu diseño es muy extraño... vas a tener muchísimos datos redundantes en la bd. Si lo que quieres es distinguir entre tipos de usuarios, puedes tener una única tabla de usuarios con una columna que podrías llamar por ejemplo `id_tipo` A través de ella identificas si el usuario es profesor, alumno, etc. O lo puedes hacer con una tabla asociativa.

Comment: No, no. Viendo la imagen se ve más claro que deberías ir pensando en otro diseño. Imagina que hay dos usuarios con el mismo apellido. Luego, hacer una relación desde el nombre de una tabla con el apellido de otras dos... Noooo. Lo que puedes es tener una tabla con todos los datos de los usuarios, sin tener que tenerlos repetidos en tres tablas y además unirlos mediante columnas que te podrían llevar a hacer una relación errónea.

Comment: Intentaré hacer lo que me dice, gracias por la respuesta, veo que comenta por todos lados y da respuestas, gracias y a hacer la modificación en una hora comento si funcionó

Comment: Ahh.. agregaste mas info.. hazle caso a cedano!!

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente lo que hago en casos similares es, 
**Primero:** elegir como entidad fuerte el usuario, en ese sentido, lo primero que registro es el usuario, luego el profesor o el alumno, pues es muy probable que luego tengas un usuario que no sea profesor ni alumno.
**Segundo:** Como buena práctica, creo un atributo tipo identity autoincremental como clave primaria, lo veras en todas las tablas, para asegurar la integridad referencial en las relaciones entre entidades.

En la tabla materia no se por qué tienes el atributo calificación?, es redundante, ya que ese atributo, según tu esquema, pertenece a la entidad boletacalificacion.

Quedaría así:

[image: Diagrama Entidad-Relación]

**Sentencias DDL**

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario` (
  `idusuario` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombreusuario` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `contrasena` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `tipousuario` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusuario`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `nombreusuario_UNIQUE` (`nombreusuario` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `profesor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profesor` (
  `idprofesor` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clavenomina` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellidopaterno` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellidomaterno` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idprofesor`, `usuario_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `clavenomina_UNIQUE` (`clavenomina` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_profesor_usuario1_idx` (`usuario_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_profesor_usuario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`usuario` (`idusuario`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `alumno`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alumno` (
  `idalumno` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `matricula` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellidopaterno` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellidomaterno` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idalumno`, `usuario_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `matricula_UNIQUE` (`matricula` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_alumno_usuario_idx` (`usuario_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_alumno_usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_id`)
    REFERENCES `usuario` (`idusuario`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table  `materia`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `materia` (
  `idmateria` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmateria`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `nombre_UNIQUE` (`nombre` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `boletacalificacion`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boletacalificacion` (
  `idboletacalificacion` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `profesor_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `materia_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `alumno_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `calificacion` FLOAT(2,2) NOT NULL,
  `promedio` FLOAT(2,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idboletacalificacion`),
  INDEX `fk_boletacalificacion_materia1_idx` (`materia_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_boletacalificacion_profesor1_idx` (`profesor_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_boletacalificacion_alumno1_idx` (`alumno_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_boletacalificacion_materia1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`materia_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`materia` (`idmateria`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_boletacalificacion_profesor1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`profesor_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`profesor` (`idprofesor`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_boletacalificacion_alumno1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`alumno_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`alumno` (`idalumno`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Sentencias DML**

```
INSERT INTO `usuario` 
        (`nombreusuario`,
        `contrasena`,
        `tipousuario`)
VALUES ('minombre_user',
        'mipassword',
        'mitipo_user');

INSERT INTO `profesor` 
        (`clavenomina`, 
         `nombre`,
         `apellidopaterno`,
         `apellidomaterno`,
         `usuario_id`)
VALUES
    (clavenomina,
    'mi_nombre',
    'apellidopaterno',
    'apellidomaterno',
     usuario_id);
```

Y así como el insert en la tabla profesor, el alumno... Pero debes tener en cuenta que, en éste esquema, primero el usuario.!

Comment: Muy completo tu comentario, de hecho mencionas muchas recomendaciones para el diseño, de verdad se nota profundidad en el tema, te agradezco tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

En el esquema que tienes ahora mismo obligas a que todo usuario tenga un registro en **AMBAS** tablas profesor y usuario. Por lo que hay que cambiar los CONSTRAINTS a las tablas de usuario y profesor en vez de ponerlos en usuario. Obviamente esto cambiaría el orden de inserción, ya que tendrías que insertar primero en usuario y luego en profesor o usuario.

Por otra parte, cambiaría lo de apellido materno y paterno por apellido1 y apellido2, ya que la ley hoy en día permite cambiar el orden de los mismos.

Tus creates quedarían tal que así.

```
CREATE TABLE usuario 
(
    fk_NombreUsuario VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Contrasena VARCHAR   (10) NOT NULL,
    TipoUsuario VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (`fk_NombreUsuario`)
);

CREATE TABLE profesor 
(
    ClaveNomina INT (8) KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    ApellidoPaterno VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    ApellidoMaterno VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    NombreUsuario VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT fk4 FOREIGN KEY (NombreUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (fk_NombreUsuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    INDEX ( `NombreUsuario`)
);

CREATE TABLE alumno 
(
    Matricula INT (8)  KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    ApellidoPaterno VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    ApellidoMaterno VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    NombreUsuario VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT fk5 FOREIGN KEY (NombreUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (fk_NombreUsuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    INDEX ( `NombreUsuario`)
);
```

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, no sabía sobre el orden de los apellidos, es un punto muy valido, por cierto gracias por tu analisis